# Difference between plug-ins and frameworks

Tags: macos, plugins, frameworks

What is the difference between frameworks and plug-ins? i.e Which factors decide when to use plug-ins and frameworks?

Comment: This question feels primarily opinion-based, and thus is eligible for closure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Frameworks provide functionality, which programs must be written to use; plugins extend something else's functionality, usually in a way that doesn't require rewriting existing programs to use.  You may well use both, with a framework that provides a basic interface and plugins that add functionality to the interface.

Examples of this are:

- PAM

  The PAM library is a framework; PAM modules are plugins.  You edit `/etc/pam.conf` or `/etc/pam.d/*` to use the plugins, instead of recompiling code that uses the PAM library.  But older packages need to be rewritten to use the PAM framework instead of directly accessing various system files.
- NSS

  Similarly, NSS consists of a framework and a set of plugins that provide functionality within that framework.  In this case, most things don't need to be recompiled because the interfaces provided by an older framework (`libc`'s `getpwent` and similar functions) were mostly sufficient for the new one.  (The exception being anything that relied on the shadow password file, or for even older programs the password in the regular password file.)  Configuration involves editing `/etc/nsswitch.conf` insyead of modifying programs.
- Cyrus SASL

  Similar to the above, the SASL library is a framework, but the authentication mechanisms are plugins.  Configuration is mostly by files in the SASL lib directory, although there is also an interface used by some programs which allows it to be embedded in those programs' own configuration files; again, in either case it doesn't require recompiling to add, change, enable or disable mechanisms.
- On Mac OS X, services are implemented as plugins; the corresponding framework is built into the standard frameworks.

There are similar frameworks and plugins for Windows, but I don't really know enough about Windows to point to any good examples.

In any case, the general rule is that you use a framework to provide interfaces for programs to access functionality, and use plugins within a framework to provide or extend its functionality.